# difference between web3.js , web3.min.js, web3-light.js , web3-light.min.js

Tags: web3js

I git clone the web3j and found in the fold dist there are web3.js , web3.min.js, web3-light.js , web3-light.min.js

Whats the difference between web3.js , web3.min.js, web3-light.js , web3-light.min.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**:

`web3.js` contains the [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) module while `web3-light.js` does not.

`min.js` suffix means library is minified (code is unreadable) and compressed.

**Long answer:**

`web3.js` is [open-source](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/gulpfile.js) project, so lets see what's inside. `Web3` use Gulp build system to produce different  versions of library. The code responsible for `light` flavour looks like this:

```
gulp.task('light', ['clean'], function () {
    return browserify(browserifyOptions)
        .require('./' + src + '.js', {expose: 'web3'})
        .ignore('bignumber.js')
        .require('./lib/utils/browser-bn.js', {expose: 'bignumber.js'}) // fake bignumber.js
        .add('./' + src + '.js')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(exorcist(path.join( DEST, lightDst + '.js.map')))
        .pipe(source(lightDst + '.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( DEST ))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
        .pipe(rename(lightDst + '.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest( DEST ));
});
```

[uglify()](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) function is responsible for minification process. Generally, `min` version is use in production, while without `min` - in development.